# How to order a list according to an arbitrary order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I searched a relevant question but couldn't find one. So my question is how do I sort an array based on an arbitrary order. For example, let's say the ordering is:

```
order_of_elements = ['cc', 'zz', '4b', '13']
```

and my list to be sorted:

```
list_to_be_sorted = ['4b', '4b', 'zz', 'cc', '13', 'cc', 'zz']
```

so the result needs to be:

```
ordered_list = ['cc', 'cc', 'zz', 'zz', '4b', '4b', '13']
```

please note that the reference list(order_of_elements) describes ordering and I don't ask about sorting according to the alphabetically sorted indices of the reference list.

You can assume that `order_of_elements` array includes all the possible elements.

Any pseudocode is welcome.

Comment: Any complexity requirements?

Comment: Actually my problem is easy so there isn't any requirement for me but I just wanted to know if there is a specific algorithm or approach for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and Pythonic way to accomplish this would be to compute an index lookup table for the `order_of_elements` array, and use the indices as the sorting key:

```
order_index_table = { item: idx for idx, item in enumerate(order_of_elements) }
ordered_list = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda x: order_index_table[x])
```

The table reduces order lookup to `O(1)` (amortized) and thus does not change the time complexity of the sort.

(Of course it does assume that all elements in `list_to_be_sorted` are present in `order_of_elements`; if this is not necessarily the case then you would need a default return value in the key lambda.)

Comment: I made that implicit assumption that order_of_elements includes all the possible elements. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a limited number of possible elements, and if these elements are hashable, you can use a kind of counting sort.

Put all the elements of `order_of_elements` in a hashmap as keys, with counters as values. Traverse you `list_to_be_sorted`, incrementing the counter corresponding to the current element. To build `ordered_list`, go through `order_of_elements` and add each current element the number of times indicated by the counter of that element.

```
hashmap hm;
for e in order_of_elements {
    hm.add(e, 0);
}

for e in list_to_be_sorted {
    hm[e]++;
}

list ordered_list;
for e in order_of_elements {
    list.append(e, hm[e]); // Append hm[e] copies of element e
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Just out of curiosity, is the complexity O(n) here assuming that the append operation is O(1)?

Comment: Indeed it is. You traverse `order_of_elements` twice and `list_to_be_sorted` once. Hashmap insertions and lookup are of amortized constant complexity. Append (of one element) is constant on a linked-list, amortized constant on an array, and constant on a pre-sized array. So, overall, the complexity is amortized `O(n)`, as would a usual counting-sort with hashmap would be (instead of `O(n log n)` for usual comparison-based sorts).

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

1. create an auxiliary array which will hold the index of 'order_of_elements'
2. sort the auxiliary array.

   2.1 re-arrange the value in the main array while sorting the auxiliary array